# Summing values in a dictionary of lists and counting all zero values for the first items in the lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary `dictData` that has been created from 3 columns (0, 3 and 4) of a csv file where each key is a datetime object and each value is a list, containing two numbers (let's call them a and b, so the list is [a,b]) stored as strings:

```
import csv
import datetime as dt
with open(fileInput,'r') as inFile:
        csv_in = csv.reader(inFile)    
        dictData = {(dt.datetime.strptime(rows[0],'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')):[rows[3],rows[4]] for rows in csv_in}
```

I want to do two things: Firstly, i want to sum each of the values in the list(i.e sum all the a values, then sum all the b values) for the whole dictionary. If it was a dictionary of single values, I would do something like this:

```
total = sum((float(x) for x in dictData.values()))
```

1. How do I change this so that `.values` identifies the first (or second) item in the list? (i.e. the a or b values)
2. I want to count all the zero values for the first item in the list.

Comment: "How do I change this so that .values identifies the first (or second) item in the list?". Can you elaborate: I don't follow

Comment: So each item in the dictionary is a list of 2 values [a,b] I want to sum all the a values in the dictionary... will edit to make it clearer

Comment: Maybe give a concrete example of what you want. The csv file also seems irrelevant: where the data is coming from doesn't have anything to do with your problem

Comment: So are you summing over tuples or a list of lists? You want to go from input of `[(0,1), (2,3), (4,5)]` to output of 15?

Comment: Not quite. i want an output of 6 and an output of 9.
And it is a dictionary of lists:
{date1: [0,1], date2:[2,3], date3:[4,5]}

Comment: Errr, 1, 5, and 9? I'm confused where 6 came from

Comment: 0 + 2 + 4 =6
1 + 3 + 5 =9

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Setup

```
dictData = {'2010': ['1', '2'],
            '2011': ['4', '3'],
            '2012': ['0', '45'],
            '2013': ['8', '7'],
            '2014': ['9', '0'],
            '2015': ['22', '1'],
            '2016': ['3', '4'],
            '2017': ['0', '5'],
            '2018': ['7', '8'],
            '2019': ['0', '9'],
           }

print 'sum of 1st items = %d' % sum([float(v[0]) for v in dictData.values()])
print 'sum of 2nd items = %d' % sum([float(v[1]) for v in dictData.values()])
print 'count of zeros   = %d' % sum([(float(v[0]) == 0) for v in dictData.values()])


sum of 1st items = 54
sum of 2nd items = 84
count of zeros   = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
values = [(0,1), (2,3), (4,5)]
values = np.array(values)
print values[:, 0].sum()
print values[:, 1].sum()
print len([item for item in values[:, 0] if item == 0])
```